# Glib main loop events

Tags: c, gtk, glib

Could anyone provide me with way to connect to glib main loop events? I see no well-written tutorials about it nor description in documentation. I've never done it before and didn't use glib in any way. Is it even event-oriented or more like WinAPI?
Would be grateful for answers.

Comment: Did you find [The Main Event Loop](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html)? There are some [code examples here](http://devlib.symbian.slions.net/s3/GUID-7FD05006-09C1-4EF4-A2EB-AD98C2FA8866.html).

Comment: [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) are you sure you have to connect to glib main loop events?

Comment: Not necessarily to be frank. However it seemed the only way to handle incoming events in main loop.

Comment: What kind of events you want to handle?

Comment: I wondered about timer and listening on socket. In code I was provided with there is a mechanism based on conditional variable, though I don't understand how it works, like there are no event that application is listening to. However, I found one handler that is added through strange xml files and that was the handler that I was looking for (I asked the question because I couldn't find any connection between modules I got).

Answer (score 0):

For timers use [`g_timeout_add`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add) if you don't have hard synchronization requirements. To listen on sockets, give a look to [GIOChannel](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-IO-Channels.html).